# Compass SearchableDynamicProperty Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, compass-lucene, searchable

I have a project where I am using hibernate with compass for indexing, now everything is working fine with normal `@SearchableProperty @SearchableCompoenet` etc.

But I am facing problem when I have tried to implement `@SearchableDynamicProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issues and resolved it...

**:: PROBLEM ::**

The insert statement was not performing inside single hibernate transaction, so that's why it was not being able to index the child table entries.

**::RESOLUTION::**

After firing the insert statement on child tables, following statement (of course in synchronized state) will update the current compass indexes..

```
compassGps.index(Test.class);
```